# Azure Synapse Sql pool not receiving data from Azure Synapse Studio Dataflow

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

Background: I am working my way through an exercise where I use a dataflow in Azure Synapse Studio to transform data inside a Azure Synapse SQL pool.

Here is the exercise: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/learn/modules/populate-slowly-changing-dimensions-azure-synapse-analytics-pipelines/4-exercise-design-implement-type-1-dimension

I have gotten all the way though the exercise to the last part - testing. The data preview shows the correct data:

[image]

but after I trigger the pipeline, wait for it to run & refresh the database, I get no output from the pipeline:

[image]

and no data in the `DimCustomer` table:

[image]

I have run a test on the connection and it come back fine.

Any assistance would be great! I hope/suspect I am missing something obvious.

My current guess is that the issue is between the sink and the pipeline outcome.

Answer (score 0):

When you trigger the pipeline, does it show you something like below? If the answer is NO, then that's the problem. As the table which you are querying is the last step of the pipeline. If the pipeline was never triggered, the data never reached the sink.

[image]

Can you please check how you have configured if one the sink by mistake you have not selected "Delete option" ?